# Any software transforming broken lines into curves?

Tags: graphics

do you know of any software that would help me transform a broken line into a curved line? For example, I have an octagon or a heptagon and I want it to be transformed into something resembling a circle. if you know such software, please, let me know. Thank You!

---

Update A:

Here is an image from the tutorial given to me by Jamie Keeling (right now it's the first answer below). At least the picture there represents what I want. In that tutorial this process is called "flattening paths". I will try to put that image right here, but if it doesn't get displayed, you can find it by this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536364%28v=VS.85%29.aspx  The red line in the picture is what I would want to submit, and the blue line is what I would want to get in the end:

[image]

Comment: What language? You haven't said :)

Comment: How are the broken lines represented? How would a curve be represented? On a computer screen there are no curves - just broken lines ... :)

Comment: @ Chris Dennett: Hello Chris! Well, it doesn't really matter what language - I don't want to get into details this time, I just want a piece of software, in which it would be possible to submit some broken lines (by submitting an image or by drawing those broken lines in that software's interface) and make them "less broken", that is "more curved" as I have described.

Comment: @ Richie: Hello Richie! well, it doesn't, really matter how they would be represented. I just want a software, in which I could submit my image with broken lines or draw those broken lines in that software and then trnasform them into curves.

Comment: Comments indicate that OP wants software to do the job, not dev help. Moving to SU.

Comment: @ Marc Gravell: Thanks for allocating my question at the appropriate place and I am sorry for having posted it originally at the wrong place. You could've addressed me personally instead of just saying "OP wants..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were thinking of using C++ (I'm assuming so as you've not specified) you can use the GDI+ system that is present, there's quite a few tutorials on it on MSDN.

You will need to devise your own classes to automatically create a curve though, unless it's included and i've missed it.

[Lines, Curves and Shapes in GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536337(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @ Jamie Keeling: Hello Jamie!!! Yes, I think GDI+ is what I need, except I am a little bit afraid of the need of learning a new programming language. However, in that tutorial that You gave me, it seems that flattening paths ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536364%28v=VS.85%29.aspx ) is what I need.The red line there on the picture is what I would submit, and the blue line is what I would want to get in the end.

Comment: Excellent, i'm glad it's working well for you. I've only used it once or twice to play around with but it's a pretty powerful tool. Maybe you could examine the GraphicsPaths::Flatten method in detail and see how it works, you might be able to reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question correctly, please let me know if this isn't what you meant.

You could do this with Photoshop.  Invidivually, you could

1. select edges
2. feather the selection
3. stroke or fill the result

I would imagine this is possible for multiple shapes using Photoshop Scripting.

Comment: @ Lord Torgamus: Hello Lord!!! Thank you very much for these instructions. I will try doing it in Photoshop. Do You think the same would be possible in PhotoImpact? Also, please refer to "Update A" in my question (above) to see what I meant to say. I think this process is called "flattening paths". Is it what You are suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

What about using [Splines](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/)?

> Splines are a mathematical means of representing a curve, by specifying a series of points at intervals along the curve and defining a function that allows additional points within an interval to be calculated.  There are various functions available to approximate a curve, but in this article we will focus on a variety of spline known as the Catmull-Rom spline.

Comment: @ Mike Daniels: Hello Mike!!! Yes, it looks like it is what I really need (please, refer to "Update A" section in my question). But what software is it? Where can I download it from?

Comment: @brilliant, This is a programming question and answer site.. I assumed you needed an algorithm to implement! I don't know of software that does this specifically.

Comment: @ Mike Daniels: Yes, Mike, I understand that. However, your suggestion to use splines is quite useful. I think I will go this way. Thank You.

Comment: Don't settle for inferior splines; they should be reticulating or better.